# confusion on looping json multidimensional array using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json data like this,

```
var menuItems = {
    data:
    {        
        dataA: 
        {
            cmClass: "classA",
            cmID: "a",
            properties: [
                { cId: 'testa', cClass: 'edit', aId: 'sa', text: 'sample a' },
                { cId: 'testaa', cClass: 'cut', aId: 'saa', text: 'sample aa' }                
            ]
        },
        dataB: 
        {
            cmClass: "classB",
            cmID: "b",
            properties: [
                { cId: 'testb', cClass: 'edit', aId: 'sb', text: 'sample b' },
                { cId: 'testbb', cClass: 'cut', aId: 'sbb', text: 'sample bb' },
                { cId: 'testbbb', cClass: 'copy', aId: 'sbbb', text: 'sample bbb' },
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

I want to loop through all the data and create a unordered list out of it. So for testing im having the following jquery,

```
    $.each(menuItems.data, function (i) {
    $.each(this, function (key, value) {
    {
        alert(key + " : " + value);
        if (key == "properties") {
            $.each(value, function (key1, value1) {
                alert(key1 + " : " + value1);
            })
        }
    }
    });          
});
```

the first alert is showing properly as "cmClass : classA", "cmId : a" etc., but the second loop it is always giving "0 : [object object]", "1 : [object object]" etc., Im stuck here, i tried different cases but nothing seem to work. Is it anything wrong with the json data? can anybody help? im stuck here

Comment: Much easier to debug if you use `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Comment: thx.. thts a good one... but the solution for actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loop over objects, therefore you need to do another loop inside the $each.

```
$.each(menuItems.data, function (i) {
    $.each(this, function (key, value) {
    {
        console.log(key + " : " + value);
        if (key == "properties") {
            $.each(value, function (key1, value1) {
                for(k in value1) {
                   console.log( key1 + ':' + k + ':' + value1[k]);
                }
            })
        }
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: just one doubt, how can i access like cmClass, cmId instead of generically accessing from variables?

Comment: @Reuben when you know the parent key you could do it by: menuItems.data.dataA.cmClass

Comment: yes michel, i understand tht.. but wen we r looping, is it possible to say this.cId in the second loop?  because it is giving as 'undefined' for me..

Comment: sorry for the previous comment.. i misplaced it in the wrong place.. it is working perfect.. thanks a lot :)